# How can I loop through some files in my script?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop

I am very much a beginner at this and have searched for answers my question but have not found any that I understand how to implement.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a script:

```
FILE$=`ls ~/Desktop/File_Converted/`
mkdir /tmp/$FILE
mv ~/Desktop/File_Converted/* /tmp/$FILE/
```

So I can use Applescript to say when a file is dropped into this desktop folder, create a temp directory, move the file there and the do other stuff.  I then delete the temp directory.  This is fine as far as it goes, but the problem is that if another file is dropped into File_Converted directory before I am doing doing stuff to the file I am currently working with it will change the value of the $FILE variable before the script has completed operating on the current file.

What I'd like to do is use a variable set up where the variable is, say, $FILE1.  I check to see if $FILE1 is defined and, if not, use it.  If it is defined, then try $FILE2, etc...  In the end, when I am done, I want to reclaim the variable so $FILE1 get set back to null again and the next file dropped into the File_Converted folder can use it again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to this so I don't know where to begin.

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Sounds like a LIFO. No, I don't know how to do that in bash.

Comment: Variables don't change their values once they're assigned without being explicitly reassigned -- adding a new file won't modify what a glob already in a variable results to -- and also are unique to a single script execution (so two copies of the same script can have two different values in `$FILE1`; they won't change each other). Now, if the _temporary directory_ that's shared is being stomped on, that would make more sense.

Comment: Your AppleScript, inotify, cron job, or whatever can kick off the script. If you use mktemp, you won't have to worry about concurrent runs clobbering each other.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little difficult to parse, but I *think* you're not really understanding [shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) or [looping constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs). The globs are expanded based on what's there *now*, not what might be there earlier or later.

```
DIR=$(mktemp -d)
mv ~/Desktop/File_Converted/* "$DIR"
cd "$DIR"
for file in *; do
    : # whatever you want to do to "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  If I get you guys right, the script can be kicked off by dropping in a file and the instance of the variable for that instance of the script will not change if another file is dropped into the folder and another instance of the script is kicked off.  That makes things vary simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a LIFO -- multiple copies of the script run for different events won't have conflict over their variable names. What they *will* conflict on is shared temporary directories, and you should use `mktemp -d` to create a temporary directory with a new, unique, and guaranteed-nonconflicting name every time your script is run.

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d mytemp.XXXXXX)
mv ~/Desktop/File_Converted/* "$tempdir"
cd "$tempdir"
for f in *; do
  ...whatever...
done
```

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is a classic *race condition,* in which it is not clear that one operation will finish before a conflicting operation starts.  These are not easy to handle, but you will learn so much about scripting and programming by handling them that it is well worth the effort to do so, even just for learning's sake.

I would recommend that you start by reviewing the `lockfile` or `flock` manpage.  Try some experiments.  It looks as though you probably have the right aptitude for this, for you are asking exactly the right questions.

By the way, I suspect that you want to kill the `$` in

```
FILE$=`ls ~/Desktop/File_Converted/`
```

Incidentally, @CharlesDuffy correctly observes that "using `ls` in scripts is indicative of something being done wrong in and of itself. See [mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)."  One suspects that the suggested `lockfile` exercise will clear up both points, though it will probably take you several hours to work through it.

Comment: It's more than that -- using ls in scripts is indicative of something being done wrong in and of itself. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  Thanks.  My revised answer now reflects your comment.